# Previous date passed to backend when parsed with DatePipe Angular

Tags: angular, date

I have the following code

```
var userdate = new Date();
var datePipe = new DatePipe();
this.userDob = datePipe.transform(userdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

When I pass this.userDob to backend, I am getting the previous date being selected. Any help regarding this.

Comment: can you post some example

Comment: is userdate correct day?

Comment: yes it is correct day. @Frecia

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky issue to keep track of, one reason could be that since js gets the date from the client, he could be in any timezone. To get you on the right track, check doing something like forcing [correct timezone(list)](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/8481876):

```
let userdate = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })
```

Or if you are getting hits from any timezone one option would be to convert all dates to UTC:

```
let userdate = new Date().toUTCString(); // keep in mind utc might not match your timezone
```

However this is only if the problem is not with your datePipe implementation or the server.

Comment: you could use getTimezoneOffset().The getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time zone difference, in minutes, from current locale (host system settings) to UTC.

Comment: but if your userdate variable contains correct date and time then i dont think this will help your case.... :/